# Is there a word that describes the phrase "hope for the best,expect the worst"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The meaning of that word doesn't have to have the exact same meaning but something close enough.

Comment: Underestimate might work.

Comment: I would probably go with either "cautious optimism" or "guarded optimism". You expect something to be fine but are also aware of (and hopefully prepared for) the possibility of things turning out badly.

Comment: I think you mean "hope for the best, prepare for the worst." Your version comes from Mel Brookes - “Hope for the Best. Expect the worst. Life is a play. We're unrehearsed.”  The latter is a deliberate distortion of the original and has a different meaning.

Comment: I use "cautiously pessimistic."

Answer (score 10):

*[Preparation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preparation)*:

> noun
>
> 1.0 [MASS NOUN] The action or process of preparing or being prepared for use or consideration:
> *the preparation of a draft contract
>
> the
> project is in preparation*
>
> 1.1 [COUNT NOUN] (usually preparations) Something done to get ready for an event or undertaking:
> *she continued her preparations for the
> party*
>
> **Origin**
>
> Late Middle English: via Old French from Latin praeparatio(n-), from
> praeparare 'make ready before' ... from prae 'before' + parare 'make ready' (see [prepare](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prepare)).
> <sub>*ODO*</sub>

*Hope for the best* is a baseline mental *preparation* that motivates and supports all other *preparation* activities. *Expect the worst* begins to identify the obstacles that must be overcome to achieve success. The remaining preparation steps flow intuitively from there:

- slicing every obstacle into discrete challenges
- developing a detailed plan to meet each challenge
- practicing all the necessary steps to overcome every obstacle

This *preparation* systematically transforms the hope into confidence, which can then be leveraged in the final deployment of the plan.

Comment: +1 When I read the question, the Boy Scout motto, *Be prepared!* sprang to mind.

Answer (score 1):

My husband is sick of this word...

When he leaves the house with two dollars in his pocket, or, no jacket because, "It's a nice day out" - even though he won't be back until night...

And I, I am the Harpy from Hell, because I repeat this word *ad alta voce* each winter morning when he heads out without a hat and gloves because he's "gonna be in the car" and there is no such thing as a flat tire or breakdown in his universe...

The word is: ***contingency***.

Answer (score 0):

The word [***pragmatic***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/pragmatic) is close to the sense of the phrase:

> adjective
>
> 1. Dealing with things sensibly and realistically in a way that is based on practical rather than theoretical considerations:
>    *a **pragmatic** approach to politics*

The notion is that a *pragmatic* approach to a problem is one that is likely to succeed (hope for the best), but takes into account that unexpected situations may arise (expect the worst).